# Symfony 2 - Access public asset directly

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I have a folder called "cdn" in my /web folder and i would like to give a public access to a javascript file in there (basically, it's a bookmarklet). I don't want to use a controller to serve the file but rather let the server serve the file directly.

How could i do that in Symfony 2 ? (PS i' also using assetic)

Thanks you in advance,
Romain

Comment: I guess you need to add a rewrite rule in `.httaccess`

Comment: I think that Symfony's original `.htaccess ` does allow that. What happens when you type in asset's URL in browser? No route found or?

Comment: I've though about that, but .htaccess is not portable enough (i'll probably user Nginx in the production server)

Comment: I'v found a temporary way. Use {{ asset('asset/relativepath') }} will give me the link to the asset and i'll just have to add the domain. But i'd like somehting more portable as well (ie. automatic domain, and with the app_dev when not in production).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different directory by defining the root of your *public* folder by using [`assets_base_urls`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) in your configuration:

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>:

```
templating:
    assets_base_urls: "%assets_base_urls%"
```

This will use the value defined in specific contexts:

<kbd>app/config/config_dev.yml</kbd>:

```
parameters:
    assets_base_urls: "http://localhost/.../cdn/"
```

<kbd>app/config/config_prod.yml</kbd>:

```
parameters:
    assets_base_urls: "http://cdn.example.com/"
```

This URL should points to a directory on your server, e.g. `/var/www/site/public/`.

You'll have to [dump the assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-dumping) to the corresponding directories in both contexts in order to put the files to the right directory:

```
# dev
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev .../cdn --no-debug
# prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod `/var/www/site/public/` --no-debug
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the direct URL. The "end-asset" aka www.domain.com/path/relative/to/web/asset.img is never served by the application, but by the server.

Therefore, whichever webserver you use accesses that asset directly.